# How to specify a default UploadFile file in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

In FastAPI you can specify default values for `pydantic` models.

Is there a way to specify a default `UploadFile` so it can be shown in the `Swagger OpenAPI` documentation to try it out?

`FastAPI` application example for `UploadFile`:

```py
from logging import debug

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.datastructures import UploadFile
from fastapi.params import File

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("default_file_upload")
def default_file_upload_example(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("test:app", debug=True, port=8000)
```

How can I set a default file for the `file` parameter so it is showed as default in the `/docs` to try it out:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, just uploaded a code snippet and a screenshot, to show where I want the default file to be displayed

Comment: Since it's meant to supply to file from the user, I'm not sure if you can provide a default file and its content. There doesn't seem to be any way to provide default file content in the openapi 3.0 or 2.0 specifications: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/